# How to create a hollow pie chart using JFreeChart library

Tags: java, jfreechart

How can I create a hollow pie chart using the JFreeChart library?

If it's not possible using JFreeChart then can anyone recommend a library I can use to create a hollow pie chart like this example:

[image: example hollow pie chart]]

Answer (score 2):

its possible in JFreeChart, Try something like this .

```
RingPlot plot = new RingPlot(dataset);
StringBuffer chartFileName = new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(generatedCharts)).append(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())).append(".png");

JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
chart.setBackgroundPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point(0, 0), new Color(20, 20, 20), new Point(400, 200), Color.DARK_GRAY));

TextTitle t = chart.getTitle();
t.setHorizontalAlignment(org.jfree.ui.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
t.setPaint(new Color(240, 240, 240));
t.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 26));

plot.setBackgroundPaint(null);
plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
plot.setLabelGenerator(null);
plot.setSectionDepth(0.35);
plot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(false);
plot.setSimpleLabels(true);
plot.setShadowPaint(null);
plot.setOuterSeparatorExtension(0);
plot.setInnerSeparatorExtension(0);
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{1}",new DecimalFormat("#,##0"), new DecimalFormat("0.000%")));
plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(null);
plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(null);

Font font=new Font("",0,16);
plot.setLabelFont(font);

chart.getLegend().setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
chart.getLegend().setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM); 
chart.setBackgroundPaint(java.awt.Color.white);
chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(4, 8, 2, 2));
```

Out put will be

[image]